# How can I create a new routing protocol using Windows Server 2016 on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, remote-access, windows-server-2016

[ServerFault question I was following.](https://serverfault.com/questions/865914/connected-to-windows-server-2016-vpn-on-aws-but-could-not-ping-resources-in-vpc)

I got to step 4 of the linked answer, however when I tried to create a "New Routing Protocol" in the Routing and Remote Access menu on Windows Server 2016 it presented me with a pop up saying "No additional routing protocols are available for installation".

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that either you did not install routing (Step 2) or that you already have routing configured. What version of Windows Server 2016? How many Ethernet adapters (you should have two).

Comment: You are correct. I installed Routing and was able to continue. I reached a new problem, I cannot seem to "Allow the ESP protocol in the security group of the server", I don't know if this is on AWS (I cannot find it there) or on Windows Server. Since you're here any ideas?

Comment: Open a new question for this. Is this during the configuration of IPSEC? More information needed in your next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Server Manager.
Install Roles and Services.
Install Routing. 
Next, Install.
Go back to Routing and Remote Access.
Right Click Server > All tasks > Restart
Wait for restart.
Try to add new routing protocol.